# plotly-dash: embed indicator graph inside of a dbc card

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash

I have been banging my head off the wall all day and cannot find a way to fit a dash indicator inside of a dash_bootstrap_components card.

It seems that the body of the card and the graph do not live inside of the card. I am not very familiar with dash so it is difficult to find a way to solve the issue.

here is what I have been able to do so far in terms of plotting the indicator:

```
fig3 = go.Figure()
fig3.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta",
    number = {"font":{"size":40},'prefix': "$"},
    value = 2045672,
    delta = {'reference': 30000},
    gauge = {'shape': "bullet"},
    title = {"text": "On Hand<br><span style='font-size:0.9em;color:gray'></span>"},
    #title='Stock On Hand',
    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
    ))
fig3.update_layout(paper_bgcolor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                   plot_bgcolor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                   autosize=False,
                   width = 200,
                   height=200,
                  )
fig3.update_traces(align="center", selector=dict(type='indicator'))
```

I am forced to specify width and height for the indicator otherwise it is way too big, however this cause issues because its size does not adjust in regards to the card.

here is the html dash code for the box and the plot:

```
html.Div(children=[

             html.Div(children=[
                html.Div(children=[ 
                    html.Div(children=[
                      dbc.Card(
                        [dbc.CardBody(
                            [dcc.Graph(figure=fig3)
                             ]
                        )],className="card", style={"width": "15rem", "height":"8rem"}
   
                    ),
                ], className='jumbotron', style={'background-color': '#fffffff'}),
                    
                ])
            ],className="col-3 mx-auto"),

           ],className="row p-0 h-100", style={'background-color': '#f7f7f7', 'height':110}),
    ], className="full-width p-0 h-100", style={'background-color': '#fffffff'}),
```

and here is what the final output looks like:

[image]

I am not sure what else I can try to bring the graph inside of the box, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Any update on this? Have you looked at my answer. Are you still experiencing problems?

Comment: Hey, I don't remember seeing your answer but found a working solution. All my appologies if I didnt give credit where its due!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the instances where you set the `height` in the `style` of dash components and the indicator doesn't get cut off.

So you can do something like this:

```
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.Div(
                            children=[
                                dbc.Card(
                                    [
                                        dbc.CardBody(
                                            [dcc.Graph(figure=fig3)],
                                            style={"width": "15rem"},
                                        )
                                    ]
                                )
                            ],
                            className="jumbotron",
                            style={"backgroundColor": "#fffffff"},
                        )
                    ],
                    className="col-3 mx-auto",
                )
            ],
            className="row p-0 h-100",
            style={"backgroundColor": "#f7f7f7"},
        )
    ],
    className="full-width p-0 h-100",
    style={"backgroundColor": "#fffffff"},
)
```

I've also changed the casing of the style properties to `camelCase` as this is what React (which dash uses) likes.